# UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible crash when setting to false

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a huge issue with my app. Whenever I set:

```
UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
```

after I had previously set it to true, I get an NSZombie which shows the following:

"An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocatedUIActivityIndicatorView' object (zombie) at address: 0x102b334d0

Can't add images because I don't have the reputation yet.. :(

but here are the links:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbARb.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5GjD.jpg

I am pretty lost here. My project is both in Swift and Objective-C. I have been doing research for the last 24 hours and couldn't find anything. The app only crashes on device, in the simulator it works perfectly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried it and got the same result.... Any idea what else might be happening? Thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind! Everything working great with that code. The problem was this: I created a UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance] and then set it to pageControl.hidden = true. Thanks for the help!